# google analytics on mvc structured site

Tags: php, model-view-controller, google-analytics

I would like to use ga for my php mvc website.

Suppose I put the code in the controller for the index page:

This means it will be triggered whenever a user goes into the index but I will have no way to determine if the user is logged in or not, right?

Because normally, if I get to a login based website the home page usually serves as the welcome screen and, in case you are logged in, as the main page for it.

How can I avoid this? I thought I could use GET parameters in the URLs so that I can see the difference between logged in / not logged in but, it looks a bit hackish.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does this have to do with MVC?

Comment: Have you looked into custom variables? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables

Comment: @deceze it *does* have to do with mvc because I might want to apply GA code on certain view pages only rather than in the controller: as stated in the question, a controller might redirect to more than one view or more routes might lead to the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your [Custom Variables - Web Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables) (ga.js)

You can also use the [Event Tracking - Web Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) (ga.js)

You have to read the full documentation of the [Google Analytic API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/) . They have provided many ways for tracking. Also read the Google Analytic Reporting API and Data Integration.